# Oracle duplicate entries bases on Two columns

Tags: oracle, duplicates

i need a query to get duplicate entries from table A on bases of two columns (Acol2 and Acol3) and Bcol3 from Table b where A.Acol4= B.Bcol2.
theefore two crequirements

1-select duplicats entries( on basis of columns Acol2 & Acol3)  and Bcol3 from table A and table B

2- where A.Acol4= B.Bcol2

I am able to write query to get duplicate entries but unable to get bcol3 with condition 2.

[image]

Comment: another home work!! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the join and then group by to find duplicates

```
  SELECT a.acol2, a.acol3, b.bcol3
    FROM a, b
   WHERE a.acol4 = b.bcol2
GROUP BY a.acol2, a.acol3, b.bcol3
  HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
```